# Learning how to use contramap when is expected (a -> Maybe b) instead of (a -> b) as the first parameter (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, option-type, contravariant

I'm studying Haskell and I was asked to solve this exercise:

> Implement a new data type named NovoPred that should have a value
>   constructor with the same name. Also it should have a field named
>   runNovoPred with type Maybe a -> Bool Then, create an Functor
>   Contravariant instance for type NovoPred

In order to solve this exercise, I've made this solution:

```hs
module Oitavo where

import           Data.Functor.Contravariant

newtype NovoPred a =
  NovoPred
    { runNovoPred :: Maybe a -> Bool
    }

instance Contravariant NovoPred where
    contramap y (NovoPred x) = NovoPred (x . y)
```

As you may notice, this solution doesn't work at all. `Contramap` needs to have this structure: `(a -> b) -> f b -> f a`, the problem is that `x` function expects to receive a value that looks like `Maybe b` and it is actually receiving a value `b` because that is what `y` function returns. Therefore, it is impossible to do `x . y`, because `x` expects to receive a value that doesn't match with what `y` is actually returning.

So, I think I need a way to make `y` function return a value of type `Maybe b`. Unfortunately, I don't have a clue on how to do it since `contramap` expects to receive something like `a -> b` as first parameter instead of something like `a -> Maybe b` (that's what I need). Could you give me a hand with that?

Comment: In `NovoPred (x . something)`, the `something` not only should return a `Maybe a` but also it receives a `Maybe b`. Now how can you construct such a function from `y :: b -> a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a function `y :: a -> b` and you need to convert a `Maybe a` to a `Maybe b`, you can just `fmap` over `Maybe`:

```
contramap y (NovoPred x) = NovoPred (x . fmap y)
```